# После перехода на HTML5 появился отступ снизу у картинок

Tags: css3, html5, html, img

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты. Прошу помощи кто знает, после перехода на HTML5 появился отступ снизу у всех картинок приблизительно в 4 пикселя, в HTML4 такой проблемы не было. Вот мой упрощенный код: https://jsfiddle.net/j5k9rh30/2/

```
<div style="display:table; border:solid 1px; height:100px;">
  <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;">
    <img src="https://oc0.ru/template/bmp/logo/nv_202x34.png" style="border:solid 1px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Специально сделал выравнивание по нижнему краю, чтобы было видно зазор. Отступ только снизу больше нигде. Я новичок сильно не ругайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите у вложенного div `line-height:0`

Comment: Спасибо,помогло

Comment: и укажите тогда `border-top: solid 1px;"` вместо `border: solid 1px;"` , а то выглядит убого

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
<div style="display:table; border:solid 1px; height:100px;">
  <div>
    <img src="https://oc0.ru/template/bmp/logo/nv_202x34.png" style="vertical-align: bottom;margin-top: 65px;border-top: solid 1px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема от `vertical-align: bottom;`